# How to open a file called `stdin` in R? ... but not actual "standard input"

Tags: r, file, stdin

How do I open a file called `stdin` in R?  In other words, how to create a connection using [`file()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/connections) to an actual file called `stdin` instead of actually reading from standard input?

Here specifically, I *do not* want to open "standard input", but a file named `stdin`.

I know I can open a file called `file.txt` in R like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
input <- file("file.txt", "r")
l <- readLines(input, n=1)
cat(l)
cat("\n")
```

When running, the above script prints the first line of the file correctly:

```sh
$ cat ./stdin
first line
second line

$ Rscript program.r 
first line
```

However, when I try to open a file called `stdin`, R seems to take input from the actual standard input (keyboard / redirect):

```
...
input <- file("stdin", "r")
...
```

The above tries to take keyboard input:

```sh
$ Rscript program.r 
asdf  # my keyboard input
asdf  # output of the script

$ echo test | Rscript program.r 
test
```

How to actually open a file called `stdin`?

Answer (score 2):

The string `"stdin"` is sort of a reserved word in [`file()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/connections) that means opening standard input (keyboard/pipe/redirect).  To open a connection to an actual `"stdin"` file, you can use `"./stdin"` as an argument to [`file()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/connections), like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
input <- file("./stdin", "r")
l <- readLines(input, n=1)
cat(l)
cat("\n")
```

The above code successfully prints the first line of a file called `stdin`:

```sh
$ cat ./stdin
first line
second line

$ Rscript program.r
first line
```

There are other reserved file names for [`file()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/connections), here's an incomplete list:

- `stdin`: standard input (keyboard);
- `stdout`: standard output (terminal screen);
- `stderr`: standard error output (terminal screen).

Again, to open actual files with the above names, prefix them with `./`.

(This was tested on R 4.1.3)